# JSPF file variable access from java class file

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have a variable in jspf file. I want to access it from another java class file.is it possible to access the variable from java class file?If it is possible how i can do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible. The solution is to move the variable to the Java class and then reference the instance of the class in the JSP. For this, you can create the instance somewhere before you need it the first time and put it into the request with `request.setAttribute()`.

Later, you can get the instance from the request and access the variable.

Comment: Thank you Aaron Digulla.I will try in this way.